# Create PL/SQL Trigger based on last update date of different views table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-view

Is it possible to create a Trigger based on the last update date of different views? The one that triggers inserting entire employee and dept records in new table when `last_update_dat`e changed/updated?

**ex views:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "EMPLOYEE_V" AS
   SELECT employee_id
         ,employee_first_name
         ,employee_last_name
         ,emp_creation_date 
         ,emp_last_update_date 
     FROM employees;

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "DEPARTMENT_V" AS
   SELECT department_id
         ,department_name
         ,dep_creation_date 
         ,dep_last_update_date 
     FROM department_id;
```

I know that this will require 1 trigger which will apply to both tables. But is there an alternative way to avoid several updates / update of records when the trigger in both tables have been fired?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain further?  Any insert or update into these views will in fact be an insert or update of its base table already, so what would the trigger add?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Trigger that runs on two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130424/creating-trigger-that-runs-on-two-tables)

Answer (score 1):

One trigger can't be created on multiple tables. You need to create two different triggers for each underlying tables. Thanks..

Comment: Hello, can you give me an example of that trigger?