# Creating Trigger that runs on two tables in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to create a DML trigger that runs on more than one table.
That is I want to invoke the trigger when ever an insert/delete/update operation took place on tables X,Y,Z.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Trigger that runs on two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130424/creating-trigger-that-runs-on-two-tables)

Comment: Duplicate is for Oracle and my question is in mssql